# Sharing Power BI published reports with RLS as public

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, row-level-security

I am building several reports in Power BI and I applied RLS (Row Level Security) to them in Power BI Desktop and the service.

But I am not being able to generate a public link to share with external people (outside the organization or even without an account).

According to [Microsoft documentation regarding "Publishing to the web"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web) there are no limitations when RLS is applied. But there is no option of "Publish to the web" in the Service menu.

Does anyone know about any limitations regarding sharing publicly reports with RLS applied to them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RLS means that there is sensitive data in your dataset, which must not be freely available to anyone, but only authorized personnel can see it. On the other side, Publish to web gives anonymous access to this data, without knowing the user's identity. Thus it makes no sense to publicly share your RLS enabled datasets (reports over them to be precise).
As far as I know, the limitations for publishing reports to web are:

- No RLS
- No Live connection
- No organizational packs
- No R visuals